# Using sheet for presenting different views on 2 buttons actions are presenting view incorrect view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-button

```
enum ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
    case first, second
    
    var id: Int {
        return hashValue
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0..<20) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text("Item Row: \(item)")
                    Spacer()
                    Button("#1") {
                        self.activeSheet = .first
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button("#2") {
                        self.activeSheet = .second
                    }
                }
                .sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
                    switch item {
                    case .first:
                        View1()
                    case .second:
                        View2()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View1")
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View2")
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
    }
}
```

I have tried the above one but it's not working as expected for different button's action sheet.
Here it opens up View2 view only irrespective of button action ( either #1 or #2).
[Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8DxN.jpg)
[Modal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULsFy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually tapping on `List` row. If you put debug points inside button actions, you can easily see that it will jump to `#1` then `#2` after, that's why it's always showing up View2. Try to make buttons's size bigger and change buttonStyle to plain.

```swift
...
HStack {
    Text("Item Row: \(item)")

    Spacer()

    Button("#1") {
        self.activeSheet = .first
    }
    .buttonStyle(.plain)

    Spacer()

    Button("#2") {
        self.activeSheet = .second
    }
    .buttonStyle(.plain)
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `.buttonStyle(.borderless)` to your `List` will solve your issue:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0..<20) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text("Item Row: \(item)")
                    Spacer()
                    Button("#1") {
                        self.activeSheet = .first
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button("#2") {
                        self.activeSheet = .second
                    }
                }
                .sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
                    switch item {
                    case .first:
                        View1()
                    case .second:
                        View2()
                    }
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderless)  // << here
        } 
    }
}
```

P.S. you should add your `.sheet` modifier outside of the list. Ideally to the `NavigationView` or the `List` itself. *This isn't required* but I personally think having only 1 view with a sheet modifier makes more sense than every row having its own sheet modifier. This is just a preference though.

Comment: If I need to use fullscreencover for view2 and normal sheet for view1 then I can use both for different State values ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: normal sheet does not take whole screen, it presents as stack , fullscreencover takes the whole screen. Normal sheet we can close with drag down.

Comment: No I mean what do you mean by "then I can use both for different State values". I understood the first part

Comment: sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
                    switch item {
                    case .first:
                        View1()
                    case .second:
                        View2()
                    }
                }

Here instead of actionsheet, can have 2 states values for each button  i.e. pesentView1, presentView2. Then .sheet(isPresented:$presentView1) and .fullscreencover(isPresented: $presentView2).